# What happened where in 1541? (Portuguese in the Horn of Africa)

Tags: battle, 16th-century, ethiopia, portuguese-empire

Was trying to check the following description from the introduction to [a board game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/14235/kassala):

> In 1541, Portuguese soldiers [...] slipped into the port of Massawa
> [and] join[ed] the Christian forces. At the walled desert town of
> Kassala on the river Gash, in what is now Sudan, the forces of Emperor
> Galawdewos are believed to have made their climactic stand [and] the
> surviving Moslem forces withdrew to the safety of Khartoum, about two
> hundred fifty miles to the west.
>
> For two years following the battle, the emperor recruited troops.
> Then, with a force of eight thousand infantry and five hundred
> cavalry, he attacked the Moslems at Waina Rega. After sixteen years in
> Ethiopia, Ahmed Gran fell to a Christian musket ball. Although Emperor
> Galawdewos died two years later in a minor engagement, he had turned
> the Moslem tide for good at Kassala.

And also have this note (unknown source, perhaps some encyclopedia):

> 1541-1543 Eastern Africa: Ethiopia: Portuguese intervention to aid the
> Ethiopians against the Muslims, A Portuguese force under Cristovao da
> Gama lands at Massawa to support the Ethiopians against the Muslims.
> After helping end the Muslim siege of Kassala, da Gama goes on to
> defeat the Muslim forees led by Ahmed Gran in the Battle of Waim Dega
> on February 21, 1543. Gran is killed in the battle.

But when [googling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottoman%E2%80%93Portuguese_conflicts_(1538%E2%80%9357)), I find a rather different chronology:

> At Massawa, governor Estevão da Gama responded to an appeal by the
> Bahr Negus to assist the Christian Ethiopian Empire against invading
> Adalite forces. [...] On February, 1542, the Portuguese were able to
> capture an important Adalite stronghold at the Battle of Baçente. The
> Portuguese were again victorious at the Battle of Jarte [...] However,
> the Gragn then requested aid from the Ottoman governor of Yemen in
> Aden [...] In the Battle of Wofla, Somali and Turkish forces defeated
> the Portuguese, Gama was captured and killed by Gragn himself upon
> refusing to convert to Islam.
>
> Gelawdewos was eventually able to reorganize his forces and absorb the
> remaining Portuguese soldiers and defeated Gragn (who was killed) at
> the Battle of Wayna Daga [...]

All these places (Jarte, Wofla, Wayna Daga/Waim Dega/Wainadega) seem to be far south of Kassala. Based on the descriptions of the battle, [Wayna Daga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Wayna_Daga) appears to be most similar to the one portrayed in the game (minus the town of Kassala).

Was there never a siege or battle at Kassala in the 16th c.? Which information are the earlier descriptions based on?

Comment: I think you may have answered your own question here. Minor historical inaccuracies in a book of board games would hardly be surprising.

Comment: The second quotation also says siege of Kassala. I'm pretty sure the board game book is not just fantasy, it is probably a more or less verbatim quote from some history book of that era.

Comment: Here's a [drawing](https://www.reddit.com/r/portugal/comments/aajowo/cristovao_da_gama_facing_ahmed_gragn_armed_force/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x). Note that Cristóvão da Gama was the son of Vasco da Gama.